# Property of covariance of Normal random variable with an arbitrary function of that random variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation, covariance

In the paper

> Sharpee, T., Rust, N.C., Bialek, W.: Analyzing neural responses to natural signals: maximally informative dimensions. Neural Comput. 16, 223–250 (2004).

I found the following claim (equation A.1., page 242):

For any function $F(\mathbf x)$ of a Gaussian random variable $\mathbf x\in \mathbb R^n$, the following identity holds:

$$\left\langle x_i F(\mathbf x) \right\rangle = \left\langle x_i x_j\right\rangle \cdot \left\langle \frac{\partial }{\partial x_j} F(\mathbf x) \right\rangle,$$
where $\langle \cdot \rangle$ denotes the expectation operator.

This equation is obviously wrong. To see this, let $\mathbf x \in\mathbb  R^2$ and $F(\mathbf x) = x_1$. Then $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_2} F(\mathbf x) = 0$ which would imply that $\left\langle x_i F(\mathbf x) \right\rangle=\left\langle x_i^2 \right\rangle=0$ which is obviously not true for almost all normal RVs.

However, I would be curious if there is a correct version of the equation in the paper. I tried to make sense of it but was not successful. In particular, it puzzles me how the Gaussian assumption enters the equation.

Has anyone encountered a similar property of Gaussian RVs who could clarify that for me?

Comment: You don't give much context. For me it looks as if it might be some form of Price's theorem http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PricesTheorem.html

Comment: I don't have much more context. I found this equation in the paper, thought it was pretty neat but then found out that it is wrong. Now I am curious what the correct form of the equation would be. Price's theorem looks nice, but I cannot connect it to the equation above.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer to the same formula which the authors used in a different paper: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200930/expectation-of-gaussian-random-vector-arbitrary-function-thereof

Comment: I see. It was just sloppy notation. They meant the average gradient instead of the average partial derivative w.r.t. $x_j$. Thanks for the hint.